# clean way to handle future of option in scala func

Tags: scala

I have some simple enum name Result of fail/success

```
sealed trait Result

case object Success extends Result

case object Fail extends Result
```

and I have a function that get nothing and returns Future of Result,

```
def do(): Future[Result] = {

    someService.getInfo() flatMap { responseInfo =>
      responseInfo.fold(Future.successful[Result](Result)) { info =>
       myDB.getData(info.resId) map { dbRes =>
            if (dbRes.isSomething) Fail else Success
        } recover {
           case e: NotFoundException => Fail
         }
      }
    }
}
```

I dont like my solution, it looks to messy, is there a simpler one?

`someService.getInfo` returns `Future[Option[ResponseInfo]]`

and what i want to do here is incase `someService.getInfo` returns None so the func should return Future[Fail] else to call the db, which also returns Future of a case class and base on the response to return Fail/Success.

but im looking for a super stylish scala way to make it look good :)

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new concept of `Success` and `Failure`, which a `scala.concurrent.Future` already has, so what you are doing is pretty pointless.

You have all the failure state representation you could want, because inside a `Future` hides a `scala.util.Try`, so you can already `match`, `fold`, etc, any other normal flow control method is there.

```
def do(): Future[Option[DbResult]] = {

    someService.getInfo() flatMap { responseInfo =>
      responseInfo.fold(Future.successful(_)) { info =>
       myDB.getData(info.resId) map { dbRes =>
            if (dbRes.isSomething) Some(dbRes) else None
        } recover {
           case e: NotFoundException => Future.failed(e)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

It's also not a good idea to conflate notions. E.g "not finding" a result in the database for a given query is a very valid state, and it has nothing to do with your failed future.

Failures in a future should represent network failures, malformed queries, etc, not a valid roundtrip where the database correctly returned no results. For that reason you can use `Option`.

**Monad transformers**

This is a generic problem, of transforming `G[F[_]]` to `F[G[_]]`, where you have interesting combinations of wrapped types to deal with. Say `Future[Option[T]]` to `Option[Future[T]]`. The functional way of dealing with this stuff is a little bit hairy, but worth it.

```
import cats.data.OptionT
import cats.std.future._

def do() = {
  val chain = for {
    info <- OptionT(someService.getInfo())
    data <- OptionT(myDB.getData(info.resId) map { dbRes =>
            if (dbRes.isSomething) Some(dbRes) else None
        } recover {
           case e: NotFoundException => Future.failed(e)
        })
  } yield data

  chain.value
}
```

It would look similar to above. Read more about `OptionT` [here](http://enear.github.io/2016/04/11/monad-transformers/), but it looks like what you want.

Comment: no, im not creating new concept of  Success and Failure, its enums that means something to me inside my app logic, and its not the full name i just simplified it, i still want to return future of those enums

Comment: @MNY Alright no worries. Look at the second part of what you want, you would need to implement your own transformer implicits to tell cats how to de-structure your custom enum types, and what success/failure means, or stick to default types like Option, as I'm showing you above.

Comment: Success and Failure are properties of `Try`, not `Future`. Also, *because inside a Future hides a scala.util.Try* is not accurate. `Future` has no `Try` hidden in it. What you can do is get a `Try` from Futures combinators, such as `onComplete`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It's very accurate, the value inside a Future is an asynchronously completed `Try`. Look at the source code, that's what I meant by hides a `Try`. The future combinators simply offer a convenient way to expose and use the internals of the implementation.

Comment: Perhaps I failed to understand what you meant. In my head, the fact that a `Future` represents it's asynchronous computation result as a `Try` does not mean it "hides" one inside, it just means that chosen representation of the result is a `Try`, could as well be an `Either`.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov It could be yes, I just highlighted that as in the example, OP was creating a new Success/Failure. I assumed it was the actual code, not a synthesised version, so I replied in kind. The interesting argument here is not create yet another success/failure state handler for a future, because it already has one, regardless of what's underneath it.